# How to get return value from exec of a stored procedure in select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    @return_value from [dbo].[Procedure_GetData](column2 , column3),
    column2,
    column3
FROM 
    Table_name
```

Comment: I have tried every possible way i can search to do this but i cant. please guide me for any solution

Comment: Can't do this with an SP, use a UDF.

Comment: Yes thank you. it worked with scaler function call in select.